# TeeChart for PHP : Differences between image render and JavaScript Export

Tags: php, teechart

I try to use the right axis of TeeChart for PHP. I'm aware that we need to link a valid serie to both vertical axis. In fact, I have tried a simple test with the custom axis demo on the Steema site. I cut and pasted the demo and try to export it to javascript instead of rendering it.
I used this code to export to javascript :

```
echo  $tChart1->getChart()->getExport()->getImage()->getJavaScript()->Render()->toString();
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/a/tecnar.com/file/d/0B_7NzaZ6fL97NC1FSlo0MzN0UkU/view?usp=sharing) is a snapshot of the 2 renders side-by-side (sorry to put it in a link, this forum don't allow me to post pictures yet...)

Is there a way to get the right axis to show with the export?

EDIT:
Here is the code to test on your side :

```
<?php 
    //Includes 
    include "../../../sources/TChart.php"; 

    $chart1 = new TChart(600,450); 
    $chart1->getChart()->getHeader()->setText("Custom Axes Demo"); 
    $chart1->getAspect()->setView3D(false); 

    $line1 = new Line($chart1->getChart()); 
    $line2 = new Line($chart1->getChart()); 
    $line1->setColor(Color::RED()); 
    $line2->setColor(Color::GREEN()); 
    $chart1->addSeries($line1); 
    $chart1->addSeries($line2); 

    // Speed optimization 
    $chart1->getChart()->setAutoRepaint(false); 

    for($t = 0; $t <= 10; ++$t) { 
      $line1->addXY($t, (10 + $t), Color::RED()); 
      if($t > 1) { 
        $line2->addXY($t, $t, Color::GREEN()); 
      } 
    }  

    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->setStartPosition(0); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->setEndPosition(50);         
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getAxisPen()->color = Color::RED(); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getTitle()->getFont()->setColor(Color::RED()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getTitle()->getFont()->setBold(true); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getTitle()->setText("1st Left Axis"); 

    $chart1->getAxes()->getTop()->getLabels()->setAngle(45); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getTop()->getTitle()->getFont()->setColor(Color::YELLOW()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getTop()->getTitle()->getFont()->setBold(true); 

    $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->getLabels()->setAngle(0); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getLabels()->setAngle(45); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->getTitle()->getFont()->setColor(new Color(255,25,25)); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->getTitle()->getFont()->setBold(true); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getTitle()->getFont()->setColor(Color::BLUE()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getTitle()->getFont()->setBold(true); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getTitle()->setText("OtherSide Axis"); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getLabels()->getFont()->setColor(Color::BLUE()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getRight()->getAxisPen()->setColor(Color::BLUE());         

    $chart1->getAxes()->getTop()->getTitle()->setText("Top Axis"); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->getTitle()->setText("Bottom Axis"); 

    $line1->setHorizontalAxis(HorizontalAxis::$BOTH); 
    $line1->setVerticalAxis(VerticalAxis::$BOTH); 

    $axis1 = new Axis(false, false, $chart1->getChart()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getCustom()->add($axis1); 
    $line2->setCustomVertAxis($axis1); 
    $axis1->setStartPosition(50); 
    $axis1->setEndPosition(100); 
    $axis1->getTitle()->getFont()->setColor(Color::GREEN());         
    $axis1->getTitle()->getFont()->setBold(true); 
    $axis1->getTitle()->setText("Extra Axis"); 
    $axis1->getTitle()->setAngle(90); 
    $axis1->setRelativePosition(20); 
    $axis1->getAxisPen()->setColor(Color::GREEN()); 
    $axis1->getGrid()->setVisible(false); 

    echo  $tChart1->getChart()->getExport()->getImage()->getJavaScript()->Render()->toString();?>
```

Comment: I don't have the right to see that snapshot

Comment: Now everyone should have access. Sorry, first time working with Google Drive access management.

Comment: I see. Could you please arrange a simple example test project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: @Yeray See my edit on my original post...

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the end of your test page to show both the HTML5 and the PHP charts at the same page:

```
echo  $chart1->getChart()->getExport()->getImage()->getJavaScript()->Render()->toString();
$chart1->render("chart1.png");
$rand=rand();
print '<img src="chart1.png?rand='.$rand.'">';
```

Then, I've modified TeeChart PHP sources to also export the custom axes and the assign.

It now looks like this:

[image: html5 on the left, php on the right]

Please, send a mail to "info@steema.com" and we'll send you the modified unit (JavaScriptExport.php).